# etherscan api token name and symbol not shown,is this bug for etherscan?

Tags: etherscan

http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&address=0x4e83362442b8d1bec281594cea3050c8eb01311c&startblock=0&endblock=999999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

I am test etherscan for getting token transactions, it shows up but the token name and token symbol show empty, and some token the token name and symbol shows but some not, all created long time ago. Is this a bug? Thanks

Comment: is this token api documented somewhere?  All I can see at Etherscan is that it can show the total supply field and account balance for a token. Where did you get this API for getting token transactions? https://etherscan.io/apis#tokens

Comment: in account section, not in token

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with Etherscan, because the contract address that holds the tokens is not 0xecf8f87f810ecf450940c9f60066b4a7a501d6a7, but 0x7f6ECcbcA710E8B5af7d837c7e2E406844538E10 , if we talk about the first transaction with hash 0x5f2cd76fd3656686e356bc02cc91d8d0726a16936fd08e67ed30467053225a86

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. Etherscan will only show information such as the token name, symbol, total supply etc. if a token contract adheres to the ERC20 specification and provides that information using the appropriate functions.

For example, for token 0xecf8f87f810ecf450940c9f60066b4a7a501d6a7, this does not appear to be the case. They don't provide the `name` and `symbol` values as required by the specification, and are thus non-ERC20 compliant.

Comment: tnanks a lot . I saw : https://etherscan.io/address/0x4f4e14d1fe10d277c38c90700ef278601c6d4aba also shows the name of the token on etherscan but it does not shown in the API result , the API result shows empty in name in API although it shows the correct token name on etherscan website. It also mention on page https://etherscan.io/token/0x4f4e14d1fe10d277c38c90700ef278601c6d4aba, it says this token is ERC20 token but stll not shown in API

Comment: Truth is, "name" and "symbol" public properties are NOT part of the required ERC-20 standard and are completely optional. Many ERC-20 tokens implement them, but they are not required per standard, just convention. See full spec here: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard it's only 6 functions and 2 events, with the public properties as optional.